# Plotly Dash using two dcc.Interval methods to update two objects separately doesn't update graph

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am building Plotly Dash to display live "lap time" plots from racing events. I am using user socket to receive data encoded in hex characters, filter it, perform some other operations and then display on Dash. It is almost working, except the plot is not refreshing automatically. Here's how it looks:

[image: Plotly Dash LapTimes]

I initialize a socket and create two objects, first object for reading incoming data line by line and store it. Second one to put in appropriate format for displaying multiple lines on the graph. I use Interval method with interval 0 for first object, so that incoming stream of data is read constantly (instead of while True loop). Then I use Interval method again to with interval set to 5000, so the graph is updated only every 5 seconds. Now, the data is being processed correctly (I printed it out to check), the graph gets initialized, but it is not being updated. If I manually reload the Dash webpage it gets updated, but naturally I want it to refresh on its won every 5 seconds.

I read that small interval updates (like for first object) can cause the Dash not to load properly, but even if I change the interval from 0 to higher value same issue stays. Also, the data stream is fast, so I have to keep reading it non-stop. My guess is that somehow the n_intervals value gets used by both objects and that causes some problem. Also, I do get the following warning: "127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2022 15:20:24] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -", however I can suppress it and it doesn't change anything.

```
#DASH APP STRUCTURE

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.Div(id='live-update-data'),
                dcc.Interval(id = 'update-data', interval = 0, n_intervals=0)
                ]),

            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'live-graph', animate = True),
                dcc.Interval(id = 'graph-update', interval = 5000, n_intervals=0)
                ])
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('live-update-data', 'children'),
    [ Input('update-data', 'n_intervals') ]
)

def read_data_socket(n_intervals):

    part = ' '
    msg = []
    msg, part = connection.receiveAll(part)
    for line in msg:
        #print(line)
        #LapTimes
        if line.startswith('$C'):
            line = line.strip()
            lap = re.split('¦', line)
            car = int(lap[5])
            lap_time = int(lap[9],16)/10000 
            lap_num = int(lap[7],16)
  
                
            if car not in lap_times:
                lap_times[car] = []
            if len(lap_times[car]) == 0:
                if lap_time > 0 and lap_time < LAP_FILTER:
                    lap_times[car].append([lap_num, lap_time])
            else:
                if lap_times[car][-1][1] != lap_time and lap_time > 0 and lap_time < LAP_FILTER:
                    lap_times[car].append([lap_num, lap_time])

    return lap_times



@app.callback(
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [ Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals') ]
)
  
def update_graph_scatter(n_intervals):

    data = []
    maxlap = 0
    miny = 100

    for car in list(lap_times.keys()):
        if len(lap_times[car]) == 0:
            continue
        X = []
        Y = []
        for i in range(0, len(lap_times[car])):
            X.append(lap_times[car][i][0])
            Y.append(lap_times[car][i][1])
        if max(X) > maxlap:
            maxlap = max(X)
        if min(Y) < miny:
            miny = min(Y)
        plot = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                x=X,
                y=Y,
                name=str(car),
                mode= 'lines'
        )
        data.append(plot)

    return {'data':data, 'layout': go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[minlap,maxlap]),yaxis = dict(range = [miny,LAP_FILTER]),)}



### MAIN FUNCTION
### STARTS HERE

if __name__ == '__main__':

    LAP_FILTER = 65
    minlap = 1   

    lap_times = {} 

    ip = "64.85.132.67"
    port = 50008
    connection = ICReceiver()
    connection.connect(ip, port)

    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: I think that `"127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2022 15:20:24] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -",` means your request succeeded (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200))

Comment: @DerekO I saw it was considered for suppressing by [default](https://community.plotly.com/t/prevent-post-dash-update-component-http-1-1-messages/11132/2). Also, read it means that data has been posted on the [browser](https://community.plotly.com/t/dcc-intervals-and-post-dash-update-component-when-setting-animation/42075/4). However, the graph is still not getting updated

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't merged the two callbacks into one?

Comment: @emher I'm using first callback to read data from socket and second one to update plot, therefore two different intervals for each callback. I don't know if it's correct or efficient, but reading data works, just doesn't refresh the graph